# Get position of dragged clones Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update an element (named report) with the position of a cloned and dragged element. But lost as to why it's not working. So far I have:

```
 var b1h;
 var b1w;
 var b1p;
 var b1X;
 var b1Y;
 var inc = 0;

$('.drag').draggable({helper: "clone"}); $('.drag').bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) { $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
$(this).attr("id",'dragged'+inc);      inc++; console.log($(this).attr("id"));  console.log($(this).offset()); $(this).addClass("drug").appendTo('#container');  });
```

then later:

```
$('.drug').click(function(){
b1h = $('.drug').height(); 
b1w = $('.drug').width(); 
b1p = $('.drug').position(); 
b1X = b1p.left;
b1Y = b1p.top;
$('.report').html(b1h+'x'+b1w + ' Y =' + b1Y + ' X =' + b1X ); });
```

Existing elements of class drug work but not the cloned ones. Any Idea what I can do to get the cloned ones to work?

EDIT: Ok No one is responding so let me see if Ican explain better.
If I clone an element and drag it around how can I get the position from subsequent drags of that same element?

So far I can only get the position off of the first drag.

Comment: Could you post the related HTML?

Comment: all I have a to move/drag  is contained in <div class="drag">1</div>

Answer (score 0):

In your dragstop event, "this" is the drop target that invoked the event.  You seem to be adding attributes to "this". I think you intended to add the id attribute to the thing that was dragged. That would be the ui.draggable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..now I just have figure out how to change it;)